# Splitting the Db model in EF 4.1

Tags: entity, entity-framework-4.1

Anyone suggest me how to handle the following scenario.
I have some Db tables that are using in all of my projects so I am creating all these tables in every database (common tables + project tables). Now I have a common data and business libraries that depend on the common tables, I need to split these table entities into two different libs with a single DbContex.
I am using the dependency injection to pass the db context.

I am using the following Vs tools.
EF 4.1
VS 2010.

Regards,
Hareen.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use inheritance like below or

```
public class CommonContext:DbContext
{
}

public class ProjectContext:CommonContext
{
}
```

Composition like [this. (The answer I have given for your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401009/transaction-scope-in-ef-repository/6401435#6401435)